# Is there a tool to analyze a PDF in terms of fonts, objects, fields and their respective size (kb)?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

Is there a tool to analyze a PDF in terms of fonts, objects, fields and their respective sizes? It would be helpful if it ran on Windows.

I am trying to optimize the size of the PDFs we are generating via abcPDF.

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic. @dan is creating a PDF file with a library, possibly an SDK, and needs to analyze the PDF that is output. I am in a similar situation, I am using an SDK to create PDFs. I create two versions from the same project with very little difference between them, and one of them is inexplicably bloated, eight time the size of the other. I'd sure like to know where to start looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there is an optimizer within acrobat, the "PDF Optimizer" which can provide all this information.

http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/pdf/optimizer.html

Comment: Looks like the options from yms and Dingo would also work.

Comment: In Adobe Acrobat Pro DC you can find this in *Tools > Optimise PDF > Advanced Optimization*, and click the *Audit space usage...* button

Comment: Thanks @Xebozone, that pointed me in the right direction. In the new Adobe Acrobat, you can do  Save As Other > Optimized PDF > Audit space usage.

Answer (score 6):

the ***"Info tool"*** of **Multivalent** can be the answer to your question:

**Multivalent** is a java app, cross platform

download links *(latest free version with tools - build hosted on sourceforge has not anymore pdf tools, only the pdf viewer, so, don't download from sourceforge)*

- https://rg.to/file/c6bd7f31bf8885bcaa69b50ffab7e355/Multivalent20060102.jar.html

use:

```
java -cp /pathto/Multivalent.jar tool.pdf.Info -all file.pdf
```

output will look like this:

```
Filename: file.pdf
Creator: Writer
Producer: OpenOffice.org 2.4
Created: Tue Dec 11 23:08:16 GMT-08:00 2007
Page count: 51
PDF version: 1.4
image: object 11, 948x945, raw samples, depth = 8, colorspace = DeviceRGB, length = 9354
image: object 12, 948x945, raw samples, depth = 1, length = 4780
anno: page 2, object 7, Link, bounds 257.0x15.0@(34.0,50.0)
anno: page 2, object 8, Link, bounds 154.0x15.0@(79.0,20.0)
anno: page 6, object 19, Link, bounds 5.0x15.0@(318.0,514.0)
anno: page 7, object 22, Link, bounds 5.0x15.0@(170.0,415.0)
anno: page 16, object 41, Link, bounds 5.0x12.0@(97.0,241.0)
anno: page 17, object 44, Link, bounds 5.0x15.0@(196.0,413.0)
anno: page 18, object 47, Link, bounds 5.0x15.0@(106.0,444.0)
anno: page 20, object 52, Link, bounds 5.0x15.0@(129.0,557.0)
anno: page 25, object 63, Link, bounds 5.0x12.0@(353.0,531.0)
anno: page 28, object 70, Link, bounds 5.0x12.0@(117.0,194.0)
anno: page 30, object 75, Link, bounds 5.0x12.0@(303.0,104.0)
anno: page 31, object 78, Link, bounds 8.0x12.0@(172.0,404.0)
anno: page 32, object 81, Link, bounds 8.0x12.0@(278.0,530.0)
anno: page 38, object 94, Link, bounds 9.0x15.0@(206.0,118.0)
anno: page 45, object 109, Link, bounds 8.0x12.0@(151.0,541.0)
FONT NAME                        TYPE          ENCODING      EMB SUB UNI   OBJ# 
Arial-BoldMT                     TrueType      <intrinsic>    Y   Y   Y     145
LiberationSerif                  TrueType      <intrinsic>    Y   Y   Y     129
LiberationSerif-Bold             TrueType      <intrinsic>    Y   Y   Y     133
LiberationSerif-Italic           TrueType      <intrinsic>    Y   Y   Y     137
MgOpenCanonica                   TrueType      <intrinsic>    Y   Y   Y     125
NimbusRomanNo9L-Regu             TrueType      <intrinsic>    Y   Y   Y     141
149 objects
        6 fonts:  6 TrueType   6 embedded   [LUJTAY+MgOpenCanonica, QOVDSH+LiberationSerif, DSGAAE+LiberationSerif-Bold, OOGVDN+LiberationSerif-Italic, PZMJGN+NimbusRomanNo9L-Regu, FRAGCC+Arial-BoldMT]
2 images
        15 annotations:   15 hyperlinks   
 (51 pages)  Content streams command usage:   w 51   q 4502   Q 4502   cm 1   re 75   f* 24   n 51   W* 51   BT 4450   ET 4450   Tf 4450   Td 4450   Tj 1589   TJ 2861   rg 4467   Do 1
```

Comment: please, don't edit my answer referring to sourceforge for Multivalent download, since the current Multivalent build hosted on sourceforge, does not have anymore tools inside, so, it is useless

Comment: Neither of the download links work any more. How can I download it?

Comment: http://ge.tt/6fVll5H is working, just checked

Comment: Thanks. Now it does. Not sure why it didn't yesterday.

Comment: Glad to hear from you, however I'll add other links as backup as soon as possible

Comment: The links to downloads are broken. Is https://sourceforge.net/projects/multivalent/files/multivalent/ not the same?

Comment: Sorry. I'll update soon all links. Current multivalent  on sourceforge has no more the tools inside, you can download multivalent.jar with tools inside from here https://rg.to/file/c6bd7f31bf8885bcaa69b50ffab7e355/Multivalent20060102.jar.html

Comment: Unfortunatelly does not work. Eventhough I downloaded from the latest link.

Comment: you need to invoke correctly Multivalent.jar. For instance, if you downloaded Multivalent.jar in /root, the path will be:   `java -cp /root/Multivalent.jar tool.pdf.Info -all file.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

I think [Amyuni PDF Analyzer](http://www.pdfanalyzer.com/index.html) suits your needs. From the web page:

> Analyze and validate the structure of a PDF document with customizable
>   VB.NET rule sets. Ensure that a PDF structure complies with industry
>   or custom specifications.

Additionally you can automate your tests and use them as part of a batch-scripting process.

*Usual disclaimer applies*